# regex - extracting username within a file only

Tags: regex

Trying to get all the usernames in the file below.

Regex:

```
https://regex101.com/r/xcj4Rm/1
```

File:

```
The request will be processed at www.domain.com

Group name     groupA
Comment        

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auser1                    buser2                 cUser3                      
duser4                    euser5                 fuser6                 
The command completed successfully.
```

Desired output:

```
auser1
buser2
cUser3
duser4
euser5
fuser6
```

Comment: Please add your attempted regex in question from regex101 link

Comment: Also add your regex tool/flavor

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{1}

Comment: How can you tell that `duser4` is a username, but the next line with `The` is not? Are usernames always lowercase and have a minimum number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If usernames always look like `five letters` + `a number` then use

```
\b[a-z]{5}\d\b
```

##### Example [first](https://regex101.com/r/RmcIWV/1)

```py
import re

text = """The request will be processed at www.domain.com

Group name     groupA
Comment        

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auser1                    buser2                 cUser3                      
duser4                    euser5                 fuser6                 
The command completed successfully."""

print(re.findall(r"\b[a-z]{5}\d\b", text, re.I))  # ['auser1', 'buser2', 'cUser3', 'duser4', 'euser5', 'fuser6']
```

As I understand you tried to get all words after `-------------------` separated with long spaces. If so then use

```
^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+$
```

**NOTE:** `\b` matches a word boundary, and the `re.I` (ignore-case) is used to ignore case sensitivity, so it fits `cUser3`.

##### Example [second](https://regex101.com/r/OjlrQG/1)

```py
import re

text = """The request will be processed at www.domain.com

Group name     groupA
Comment        

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auser1                    buser2                 cUser3                      
duser4                    euser5                 fuser6                 
The command completed successfully."""

def extract(text):
    for groups in re.findall(r"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+$", text, re.M):
        yield from groups

print([*extract()])  # ['auser1', 'buser2', 'cUser3', 'duser4', 'euser5', 'fuser6']
```

**NOTE:** I used `re.M` (multiline) flag as regex uses `^` and `$`.

Comment: The second example actually worked better since it accounted for varying username lengths